# Request 'OPTIONS /logout' doesn't match 'POST /logout

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

I am studying Spring Cloud and Spring OAuth2 by decomposing [the three interconnected apps in this GitHub sample](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2).  When I open up the `/oauth/revoke-token` endpoint in the [`authserver` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver) and then call it from the [`ui` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/ui) with a `http://localhost:9999/uaa/logout`, the debug log for the [`authserver` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver) gives the following error message while rejecting the logout request:

```
Request 'OPTIONS /logout' doesn't match 'POST /logout
```

**What specific changes need to be made to the code in [the sample GitHub apps](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2) in order to enable the global logout to succeed when the [`ui` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/ui) calls the logout function from [`hello.js`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/ui/src/main/resources/static/js/hello.js)?**

---

**INITIAL EFFORTS:**

---

Changes that I made so far include:

Add the following @Bean definition to [AuthserverApplication.java](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java):

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {return new InMemoryTokenStore();}
```

Add the following controller class in the [`demo` package of the `authserver` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo):

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader != null) {
            String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Change the `logout()` method of [`hello.js` in the `ui` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/ui/src/main/resources/static/js/hello.js) to become the following:

```
self.logout = function() {
    $http.post('http://localhost:9999/uaa/logout', {}).finally(function() {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        $location.path("/");
    });
}
```

But when the user clicks on the logout button in the browser and triggers the call to `http://localhost:9999/uaa/logout`, the debug log for the [`authserver`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver) app gives the following output:

```
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/images/**'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.142 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/error'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/login']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/login'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/authorize']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/oauth/authorize'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/confirm_access']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/oauth/confirm_access'

2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout']
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/logout'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched

2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5790c1b4
2016-04-18 15:34:07.143 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'

2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'OPTIONS /logout' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'

2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'OPTIONS /logout' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /logout; Attributes: [authenticated]
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-04-18 15:34:07.144 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@539015a, returned: -1
2016-04-18 15:34:07.145 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ...  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]

2016-04-18 15:34:07.146 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
2016-04-18 15:34:07.146 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'OPTIONS /logout' doesn't match 'GET /**
2016-04-18 15:34:07.146 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
2016-04-18 15:34:07.146 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
2016-04-18 15:34:07.146 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2016-04-18 15:34:07.146 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/login'
2016-04-18 15:34:07.147 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-04-18 15:34:07.147 DEBUG 313 --- [io-9999-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**What other specific code changes need to be changed in [the GitHub sample apps](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2) to enable the `ui` app to trigger a global logout of the user from all apps?**

Note: Obviously, `/uaa/logout` is a different URL than `/oauth/revoke-token`.  However, the inner workings of Spring Security and OAuth in this situation are not clear without an answer to this OP.

---

**@StuXnet's Suggestions:**

---

The content of the Firefox Developer Tools Network Tab for the request is:

The request to `http : // localhost:9999/uaa/login` with method `OPTIONS` was rejected with a `403` error.

The raw `request` headers were:

```
Host: localhost:9999
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The raw `response` headers were:

```
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 20
Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 23:45:46 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application:9999
```

Next, I changed the config(http) method of LoginConfig to read as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/logout", "/oauth/revoke-token")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/logout").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
}
```

This resulted in the following new printout in the Spring Boot DEBUG logs:

```
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/images/**'
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/error'
2016-04-18 19:22:06.202 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-04-18 19:22:06.203 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/logout' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2016-04-18 19:22:06.203 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout has an empty filter list
2016-04-18 19:22:06.204 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /logout
2016-04-18 19:22:06.205 DEBUG 5319 --- [io-9999-exec-10] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/logout]
```

And the following `request` header in Firefox:

```
Host: localhost:9999
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Along with the following `response` header in Firefox:

```
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 20
Date: Tue, 19 Apr 2016 02:22:06 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application:9999
```

I then tried changing the `configure(http)` method of `LoginConfig` to become:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/logout", "/oauth/revoke-token")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        // @formatter:on
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .ignoringAntMatchers("/logout");
}
```

But the result is the following Spring Boot DEBUG log for the `authserver` app:

```
2016-04-19 10:12:13.545 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/images/**'
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/error'
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/logout' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2016-04-19 10:12:13.546 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout has an empty filter list
2016-04-19 10:12:13.547 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /logout
2016-04-19 10:12:13.548 DEBUG 4593 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/logout]
```

---

**REPRODUCING THE PROBLEM ON YOUR MACHINE:**

---

To reproduce the problem on your own machine, you can either:

1.) git clone the original sample app at the link at the top of the OP and then make the changes shown above, or

2.) Download [the zipped version of the app as it exists on my devbox including all the changes from the OP at this file sharing link](https://jumpshare.com/v/ELVSYNXNeUKV6Xl1Droq), and then:

2.a.) Untar the app.

2.b.) Navigate a terminal window to `oauth2/resource` and `mvn spring-boot:run`.  Then navigate a second terminal window to `oauth2/authserver` and type `mvn spring-boot:run`.  Then navigate a third terminal window to `oauth2/ui` and type `mvn spring-boot:run`.

2.c.) Navigate the web browser to `http : // localhost:8080`, then click `login`, then enter `user` for `username` and `password` for `password`.  After you have been authenticated, click the `logout` button to reproduce the 403 error.  Use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to examine the browser activity.  View the Spring Boot logs in the terminal that is running the `authserver` app to see Spring's activity.

3.) Either import the three folders into eclipse (or another IDE) as existing maven projects, or open the code files with a text editor to edit before repeating the relaunch and retesting in step 2.

**What else can I provide to help isolate the solution?**

Comment: @stuXnet I just added the output from the Firefox Developer Tools Network Tab.  Does this help you isolate the solution?

Comment: @stuXnet  I just added the results of trying your request to the end of my OP.  Seems to have just re-arranged the security filters without resolving the problem yet..

Comment: @stuXnet Thank you.  Please see the end of the OP, where I added the result of trying your suggestion.

Comment: @stuXnet Thank you.  I zipped up the apps as they exist on my devbox and uploaded the tar ball to a file sharing site.  I added a section to the end of the OP to give a link to the tar ball along with instructions for reproducing the problem.  You could alternatively `git clone` the original version and make the changes described in the OP.  Are you willing to try it out?

Comment: I will, but the earliest I can have a look is Saturday. And I will delete my other comments, since you tried and documented them already in the OP :)

Comment: @stuXnet Thank you very much.  I would really appreciate it.  I have been researching this API and OAuth every day for the past few weeks, but there seems to be a shortage of realisticly-featured example apps, coupled with very few people who are able to answer Spring OAuth2 questions.  Your answer to this question would help a lot of people.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the question of why you might want to do this and whether or not it is a good idea: your JS client is POSTing to an endpoint on another server, so you face two problems: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) and Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF), both of which are locked down by default in your Auth Server because it is using Spring MVC and Spring Security.

The CORS problem can be worked around in various ways, including the approach that you took, which was to punch a hole through the security configuration using a request matcher are `permitAll()`. There is a far better integration between Spring MVC and Spring Security using `HttpSecurity.cors()`. User guide link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cors. Simple example from the tutorial (vanilla resource server):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        ...;
}
```

What this does is switch on integration with the MVC declared endpoints with `@CrossOrigin`. Actually the endpoint you are trying to POST to is not one that you wrote, and it's not a Spring MVC endpoint, so you might have to use `cors().configurationSource(...)` instead.

The CSRF problem is also easy to solve in various different ways. The tutorial where you started has explicit examples showing how to do it for Angular JS (but not in the app you are using because the tutorial is not about logging out from the SSO provider). In that case we use the `HttpSecurity.csrf()` features. User guide link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf. Simple example from the tutorial in the UI app:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        ...
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}
```